# Intel ME shadow full-access OS on all Intel CPU chipsets device interface

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu, intel

So, all Intel CPUs since 2008 contain a chip inside CPU that runs a full-fledged MINIX OS with unrestrained access to RAM, devices and TCP/IP stack. It's outside of operating systems that we boot, undetectable mostly, but we have an interface exposed for it. Can one write assembly code to interface with the file server on MINIX of the Management Engine chip? Or the only way to modify it is via disassembly of bios and removing modules from bios?

Comment: I don’t know much about it, but I’m pretty sure that any code that runs on it has to be signed, so I don’t think you’ll be able to do anything with it.

Comment: Are you referring to Intel MEI? MEI is not inside the CPU, it's in the MCH/PCH (though the PCH can be in the same socket of the CPU). Also, it cannot read the OS TCP/IP stack if not indirectly by reading the memory. Access to DRAM and devices is also available to *any* PCIe device if VTd or similar are not employed. The MEI firmware has a HECI interface to *cooperative* work with the OS but this interface has no service to remove ME. To remove ME you can try *me_cleaner* (that only leaves BUP and few other modules).

Comment: The problem is that the flash area where the ME firmware resides is locked and so you must resort to an external flasher. Anyway, ME is a concern mostly to public facing servers. In your home/company you are automatically protected by the SNAT, though local attackers can access the MEI and try some exploit. Finally, I'm don't think (but not sure) ME is using MINX, rather ThreadX was the kernel of the RTOS used.

Comment: You are right about MINIX, according to Wikipedia.

Comment: @MargaretBloom: I think there's "publicity" (hype) involved - far more likely is that it's a stripped down and significantly modified fork of MINIX 3 (a derivative of MINIX 3 and possibly only a derivative of MINIX 3's kernel without any of the MINIX drivers or user-space; and not literally "MINIX 3 OS").

Comment: I think this falls into the same category as can I write my own microcode for my processor.  Technically yes with the right information/resources.  Realistically, probably not.  And why bother...

Comment: @Margaret it's very different if a device has access to DRAM or a chip with an OS. Me_cleaner doesn't remove ME, it strips down some modules from it - what remains, however, we don't know - and MINIX still runs with internal code that includes - we don't know what. I read every single network packet goes through MINIX. Wiki says there's remote access exploit to ME. There also exists an administrative remote access option in some cases.

Comment: @user145453 Well, a chip with an OS *is* a device, I don't think there's much of a difference. The ME has access to the NICs so it can potentially collects all the packets but it should do this only for its own AMT packets (or it would slow down the network). The real problem of ME, as you noted, are the exploits. The flawed implementation. That's the real problem. Intel won't spy on you and if they wanted anyway they'd not need ME since they also control all the sensitive HW (CPU, chipset, eMC, graphics).

Comment: The ME has *it's own* TCP/IP stack, but I don't think it has easy access to the TCP/IP stack of the OS running on the main IA cores.  It has access to the ethernet hardware, but not the higher levels of main OS's TCP/IP stack.  (Even if it can read the main DRAM, it would have to know where/how to look, and different OSes, or even different builds of the same OS, can use different data structures to track TCP connections and so on.)

Comment: It might have its own simple transceiver circuitry somewhere on the chipset, too. Someone nasty right nextdoor can use high-gain directional boom antenna to have extremely low-level access to every Intel computer out there.

Answer (score 3):

> Can one write assembly code to interface with the file server on MINIX of the Management Engine chip? Or the only way to modify it is via disassembly of bios and removing modules from bios?

In general; no, that would be a major design flaw.

Let's talk about trust. *Note: "trust" is not the same as "trustworthiness" (someone can be trusted when they shouldn't be).*

The fundamental basis of trust is "if they do something dodgy it will hurt them". For example; if a large company does something deliberately dodgy and get caught it effects their reputation and their profits (and they may be sued); and this is why other large companies and governments trust Intel products.

For random people (e.g. anonymous people on the Internet, a person working at an OEM assembly line, the person that drives a truck from manufacturer to retail store, the person selling computers cheap on eBay, ...); there is either no consequence or the consequence is small ("if they do something dodgy it will hurt them" doesn't apply) so there's no reason to trust them. Unfortunately lots of these untrusted people have access to the computer before the final consumer/user gets it; so to ensure something can be trusted these untrusted people have to be unable to modify it.

Essentially, to ensure Intel's ME can be trusted, people like you and me have to be unable to modify it.